# how much food should i feed my cat?

Tags: cats, feeding

I have looked a little online and most of the answers i have found are "it depends". I am curious how much it is generally recommended to feed a cat. whether by percentage of weight or volume (aka % or cups) or something else. I am fairly new to taking care of cats and i come from a snake background in which feeding is easy and well documented. My cat usually acts like he is dying of hunger when he first starts eating but sometimes will leave a few bites of food left in his bowl. I generally feed a dry bowl (1/4 cup) leaving for work and a wet bowl (1/4 cup) coming home from work. I know dry food is generally not recommended but i am transitioning from all dry diet of Iams (what his first family had) and the dry food I feed him has 4 bird products (deboned chicken, deboned turkey, and some other bird related stuff stuff that i forgot) as the main ingredients.

So is there a specific scale to use or is it really just a toss up?

Comment: Nvm found this question (dont know why it didnt show up earlier) that has some answers

Answer (score 0):

Every diet is different for it's caloric content, go by the bag (bag is usually very generous). If you add wet food on top of the recommended amount for dry you will have to cut back on dry.

Reweigh your cat every month to check for weight gains and losses, you may have to tweak the diet.